# Angular material progress bar buffer animation left to right

Tags: angular, angular-material, progress-bar

hi i want to make a progress bar with buffer animation but the animation is reversed it goes right to left i want it to go left to right or no animation at all i looked through progress bar api but couldnt find anything does angular material progress bar have a such feature

i am trying like this

```
        <mat-progress-bar
          mode="buffer"
          value="87"
          [bufferValue]="100 - 87"
          style="width: 100%"
        ></mat-progress-bar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your progress bar with buffer animation which go left to right, add the following CSS property to it.

```
::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar .mat-progress-bar-background{
    animation-direction: reverse !important;
}
```

If you want no animation, change animation's poperty to none.

```
::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar .mat-progress-bar-background{
    animation: none !important;
}
```

The following images are testing evidence for your code which are test in StackBlitz.

[image: Evidence]

[image: Evidence]

Answer (score 0):

How if we [rotate the progressbar 180 degree](https://rtkkj3.csb.app/) ?

```html
  <mat-progress-bar
    mode="buffer"
    value="87"
    [bufferValue]="100 - 87"
    style="width: 100%;"
    style="width: 100%; transform: rotate(180deg);"
  ></mat-progress-bar>
```

Comment: It wont work because the progress will be reversed to